# Fixar menu com bootstrap após descer scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-3

Estou usando **bootstrap** no meu código

Tem uma *classe* no `nav` do **bootstrap** que fixa o `nav` no **topo**

> navbar-fixed-top

Porém quero que o `nav` só fique **fixo** quando o scroll passar por ele.

Como faço isso?

Um exemplo: [Esse site](http://recodejr.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso que há um plugin capaz de fazer isso já no bootstrap, o affix, não precisa de nenhum javascript pelo que eu sei.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#affix

O menu lateral é um exemplo do uso do affix

Comment: Como faço para instalar o affix no meu html? Não consigo achar

Comment: Acho que não requer nenhuma instalação, basta copiar a tag e adapta-la para o que é preciso, aqui pode encontrar tudo sobre o affix https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Comment: Não está funcionando. Coloquei `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix-top" data-offset-top="197">` e mesmo assim não fixa @K. Chanel

Comment: Experimente ver em Try it yourself no w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp para experimentar e ver como funciona

Comment: a tag "offset-top" determina a quantidade de pixeis que é preciso fazer scroll até se afixar no topo e o que ativa o affix é a tag 'data-spy="affix"'

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei um snippet no Bootsnipp
[Navbar Affix](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/V7ppb)